# Does $NH$ not have to be a group for this to work? (Two question about a proof)

Tags: group-theory

Consider the following exercise:

Suppose that $N$ is a normal subgroup of a finite group $G$ and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$. If $|G/N|$ is prime, prove that $H$ is contained in $N$ or that $NH =G$.

I could prove it but my proof is different from the proof given in the solution and I am unsure whether the proof in the solution is correct.

Here is the proof in the solution:

Since $N \subseteq NH \subseteq G$ we have $|G:N| = |G:NH| |NH:N|$. Thus $|G:H|=1$ or $|NH:N|=1$.

Here $|G:H| $ is the index of $H$ in $G$.

There are several things about this proof that bother me:

(1) Isn't the index only defined for subgroups? At least that's how its definition is given in the book. So if both $N$ and $H$ were normal and $N \cap H = \{e\}$ then $NH$ would be a group and $|G:NH| $ would be defined.

> But is $NH$ a (sub-)group even if $H$ is not normal?

(2) The other things that's bothering me is that $|G:H| = |G|/|H|$. So  $$|G:N| = |G:NH| |NH:N|$$

becomes

$$ {|G|\over |N|} = {|G|\over |NH|} {|NH|\over |N|}$$

and of course that's always true so nothing is gained.

> In particular, I don't understand how $|G:H|=1$ or $|NH:N|=1$ follows
>   from it. Please could someone explain to me how it follows?

Comment: You miscopied something or there is a mistake somewhere: we don'h have $\;[G:H]=1\;$ as one of the options but rather $\;[G:NH]=1\;$ .

Comment: @Joanpemo It is a typo in the solution in the book then. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one of the subgroups is normal then the product is always a subgroup, and thus $\;NH\;$ is a subgroup.

As for the second doubt: remember it is given $\;|G/N|=p\;$ is a prime, and because of the multiplicity of indexes we get

$$p=|G/N|=[G:N]=[G:NH][NH:N]$$

as since the only numbers that divide the prime $\;p\;$ are $\;1\;$ and the prime $\;p\;$ itself, we either have

$$[NH:N]=1\iff N=NH\iff H\le N$$

or else

$$[G:NH]=1\iff NH=G$$

exactly as the theorem states.